# What does this ghostscript error means undefinedfilename in

Tags: c, ghostscript, postscript

I want to run the Ghostscript command for drawing lines from a C program. I am using execlp() system call to run the command. When I am trying to run the command for line drawing from terminal/C, I am getting the same error like this:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)

Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:

see the file COPYING for details.

Error: /undefinedfilename in (100)

Operand stack:



Execution stack:

   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push

Dictionary stack:

   --dict:761/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: No such file or directory

GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

The command I am running for drawing is this postscript command(drawing a line)

```
gs 100 100 moveto 300 300 lineto closepath stroke
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the flag "-c".
The  gs command will then be

```
gs -c 100 100 moveto 300 300 lineto closepath stroke
```

Comment: This is now working from terminal but it again fails to open window, when I am running this from C.

`if(fork()==0){
    execlp("gs", "gs", "-c", "100", "100", "moveto", "300", "300", "lineto", "closepath", "stroke", NULL);
}`

Comment: The command is opening a window while running in the terminal?

Comment: @BiplabRoy gs may be exiting immediately so you don't see the window. Try adding `showpage` so it waits for the Enter key.